# Cell reference in a formula generated by a another formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In cell A1 I have this formula in it:

`=OFFSET(Journey!B2,1,0,4,1)`

I have another cell with a formula that generates a cell reference (e.g. let's say cell C2 has "D10" in it.)

How do I replace "B2" in my formula with the output in cell C2 - essentially, how to inject a generated cell reference into my formula?

Thanks!

I tried:

```
'=CONCAT(CONCAT("OFFSET(Journey!", "B2"), ",1,0,4,1)")'
```

to see if I could then replace the B2 programmatically, but the generated text formula doesn't run.

Comment: look into `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 =OFFSET(INDIRECT("Journey!"&C2), 1, 0, 4, 1)
```